# Linear Algebra - Find out if the set of vectors $S$ is a basis for $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the set of vectors $S = \{x^2 + 2x, x^2 + x- 1, x^2 + 4x + 2\}$ a basis for $P_2$?

I know that the degree of the polynomial should be $ \leq 2$ but I don't know how to proceed on from there!

The polynomials linear independent.

Every quadratic polynomial (or linear/constant) be "constructed" with the given polynomials.

Comment: What canonical basis in $P_2$ do you know? Can you express $S$ in terms of this basis? What can you say about the set a vectors if their coordinates form a singular matrix? What can you say about the set a vectors if their coordinates form a non-singular matrix?

Comment: Are the polynomials linear independent? Can every quadratic polynomial (or linear/constant) be "constructed" with the given polynomials? These are the questions you need to answer here.

Comment: @imranfat updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given parameters A,B,and C. Investigate $A(x^2+2x)+B(x^2+x-1)+C(x^2+4x+2)=0$. If this can be obtained in the non-trivial way (i.e. for nonzero A,B,C's) then the given set is DEPENDENT. In fact, it happens to be dependent, but I want you to work that out. Remove brackets, collect like terms and solve the system for A,B,C. You will see that there are infinite solutions. So the given set is not a basis.

Comment: So all in all, to find out if a set of vectors is a basis of $P^2$, all you have to do is check if there are finite number of solutions?

Comment: Well, the zero element should only be made through the trivial solution. Here, that means for A=B=C=0. If that is the case, and knowing that you need three quaratic polynomials to possibly span entire P2, then that information is sufficient by the Invertible Matrix Theory. In fact, any polynomial in P2 can then be spanned uniquely for some combination A,B,C. But in your problem, it fails because zero can be made in the non trivial method as well.